# How to pass context to zsh aliases?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

This might the ultimate form of laziness but is it possible and how could I pass context of my first command to the second when working on the command line.

What I mean by this in a simple example: `brew update && brew upgrade`would turn into `brew update && upgrade` Context `{ brew }` would be just magically known by my shell.

For long commands I can pass them as variables to avoid typos but is there a tool to make more automated? I would like to just mark part of the command as context to be passed to the next one using few characters as I type along.

Comment: I don't think there is anything that would do what you want. You probably just want to define functions for commonly used chains: `buu () { brew update && brew upgrade }`

Comment: That's a shame but thoughts as much soon googling this resulted in nothing. Thanks anyways. I think I got with chains as you suggest.